# Xml index, slow count of rows

Tags: sql-server, index, performance, execution-plan, xml, query-performance

I am not getting index seek in the following scenario.
Instead of inserting `<Number>xxx</Number>` in xml column like in this post [Why is the secondary selective index not used when the where clause filters on `value()`?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/103867/why-is-the-secondary-selective-index-not-used-when-the-where-clause-filters-on), insert 100k rows with this xml `<SomeText>NiceText</SomeText>` and similar amount of rows of this `<SomeText>MoreText</SomeText>`. Doesnt need to be 100k. Just needs to be many.
Then add index

```
create selective xml index SIX_T on dbo.T(XMLDoc) for
(
    pathXQUERY = '/SomeText' as xquery 'xs:string' maxlength(8) singleton
);
```

And secondary index

```
create xml index SIX_T_pathXQUERY on dbo.T(XMLDoc)
  using xml index SIX_T for (pathXQUERY);
```

Then do a count

```
select count(*)
from dbo.T as T
where T.XMLDoc.exist('/SomeText[. eq "MoreText"]') = 1;
```

Notice that it doesnt use index seek and is "slow". Can take several seconds with millions of rows.
If i insert same values in a standard column and add an index to it and do a

```
select count(id)
    from dbo.T as T where SomeTextColumn = 'MoreText'
```

i get results instantly.
All tests done on sql server 18.3.1

The question is, how can i make counting by xml as fast as counting by column?

Thanks

Comment: Minor nitpick: 18.3.1 looks more like the version of the SQL Server Management Studio application rather than the SQL Server instance itself. You can run `SELECT @@VERSION;` in a query window in SSMS to find out the SQL Server version.

Answer (score 7):

**Data differences**

With a low amount of records to seek on, the optimizer is able to use the `SIX_T_pathXQUERY` index:

[image]

and filter on `moretext` with a seek predicate:

[image]

An interesting part here is that it executes the key lookup to get the path_1_id values that are not null.

[image]

Since that is a filter definition on the nonclustered xml index...

[image]

...while not being present in the index itself.

As a result, for the optimizer to consider using the index it knows that it has to complete these steps:

- Filter on the XML value with the secondary index on the internal
  table
- Match these returned values with the `SIX_T` clustered index on the
  internal table and filter on `path_1_id is not null` since `path_1_id` is
  not included in the secondary index
- Match these values with the actual table, `dbo.T` to return the ID to count on

**Tipping points**

When the expected rows to be returned are higher, it favours using the selective clustered XML Index, to be able to run a merge join & no key lookup instead:

[image]

with a residual predicate:

[image]

To filter on the xml column and `path_1_id`

**Comparing the plans**

You could (but you shouldn't) use the `USE PLAN` hint to force the plan with the seek on the XML column and see what would happen if we where to search on these values.

[image]

With  the execution time =

```
   CPU time = 218 ms,  elapsed time = 215 ms.
```

And the execution time for the scan + merge join plan:

```
   CPU time = 62 ms,  elapsed time = 58 ms.
```

In short, I believe that the scan with residual predicate + merge join choice was the right choice by the optimizer.

**No way around it**

While I might be wrong, I don't think there is a way to improve the count query with regular XML Indexes. 
We also cannot change these internal tables or even query them:

```
SELECT * FROM 
[sys].[xml_sxi_table_1463676262_256000];
```

It even gives a missing index hint on the merge join query plan, which you cannot create:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [<Name of Missing Index, sysname,>]
ON [sys].[xml_sxi_table_1463676262_256000] ([pathXQUERY_1_value])
INCLUDE ([path_1_id])
```

To improve the queries, you would have to look into non-xml index solutions.

---

**Edit**

> How do i use USE PLAN hint? You have example code for this query?

I would advise against this, but for testing purposes it would be fine.

**Step 1:** You would have to get the actual execution plan of the query and get
    the xml:

[image]

If you don't have the query with the low estimates, enter a value that does not exist like:

```
select count(*)
from dbo.T as T
where T.XMLDoc.exist('/SomeText[. eq "bbb"]') = 1
```

**Step 2:** Replace all `'`s with `''`s in the execution plan xml, we will need this later.

[image]

**Step 3:** Paste the plan between `OPTION( USE PLAN '')`

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM dbo.T as T
WHERE T.XMLDoc.exist('/SomeText[. eq "MoreText"]') = 1
OPTION(USE PLAN 
'');
```

**Step 4:** I had to change utf-16 to utf-8 to get the use plan hint to work

**From:**

```
OPTION(USE PLAN
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
```

**To:**

```
OPTION(USE PLAN
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

**Step 5:** Run the query.

My query now looks like this:

```
select count(*)
from dbo.T as T
where T.XMLDoc.exist('/SomeText[. eq "MoreText"]') = 1
OPTION(USE PLAN
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ShowPlanXML xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Version="1.481" Build="14.0.3223.3" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan">
  <BatchSequence>
    <Batch>
      <Statements>
        <StmtSimple StatementCompId="1" StatementEstRows="1" StatementId="1" StatementOptmLevel="FULL" StatementOptmEarlyAbortReason="GoodEnoughPlanFound" CardinalityEstimationModelVersion="70" StatementSubTreeCost="0.00986014" StatementText="select count(*)&#xD;&#xA;from dbo.T as T&#xD;&#xA;where T.XMLDoc.exist(''/SomeText[. eq &quot;bbb&quot;]'') = 1" StatementType="SELECT" QueryHash="0x412154B6AD55BBFC" QueryPlanHash="0x280B174BF20902E3" RetrievedFromCache="true" SecurityPolicyApplied="false">
          <StatementSetOptions ANSI_NULLS="true" ANSI_PADDING="true" ANSI_WARNINGS="true" ARITHABORT="true" CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL="true" NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT="false" QUOTED_IDENTIFIER="true" />
          <QueryPlan DegreeOfParallelism="1" CachedPlanSize="40" CompileTime="394" CompileCPU="301" CompileMemory="648">
            <MemoryGrantInfo SerialRequiredMemory="0" SerialDesiredMemory="0" />
            <OptimizerHardwareDependentProperties EstimatedAvailableMemoryGrant="419404" EstimatedPagesCached="52425" EstimatedAvailableDegreeOfParallelism="2" MaxCompileMemory="3655432" />
            <QueryTimeStats CpuTime="0" ElapsedTime="0" />
            <RelOp AvgRowSize="11" EstimateCPU="0" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="1" LogicalOp="Compute Scalar" NodeId="0" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Compute Scalar" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.00986014">
              <OutputList>
                <ColumnReference Column="Expr1017" />
              </OutputList>
              <ComputeScalar>
                <DefinedValues>
                  <DefinedValue>
                    <ColumnReference Column="Expr1017" />
                    <ScalarOperator ScalarString="CONVERT_IMPLICIT(int,[Expr1020],0)">
                      <Convert DataType="int" Style="0" Implicit="true">
                        <ScalarOperator>
                          <Identifier>
                            <ColumnReference Column="Expr1020" />
                          </Identifier>
                        </ScalarOperator>
                      </Convert>
                    </ScalarOperator>
                  </DefinedValue>
                </DefinedValues>
                <RelOp AvgRowSize="11" EstimateCPU="1.1E-06" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="1" LogicalOp="Aggregate" NodeId="1" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Stream Aggregate" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.00986014">
                  <OutputList>
                    <ColumnReference Column="Expr1020" />
                  </OutputList>
                  <RunTimeInformation>
                    <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="1" Batches="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" ActualExecutionMode="Row" ActualElapsedms="0" ActualCPUms="0" />
                  </RunTimeInformation>
                  <StreamAggregate>
                    <DefinedValues>
                      <DefinedValue>
                        <ColumnReference Column="Expr1020" />
                        <ScalarOperator ScalarString="Count(*)">
                          <Aggregate AggType="countstar" Distinct="false" />
                        </ScalarOperator>
                      </DefinedValue>
                    </DefinedValues>
                    <RelOp AvgRowSize="9" EstimateCPU="1E-06" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="1" LogicalOp="Aggregate" NodeId="3" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Stream Aggregate" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.00985904">
                      <OutputList />
                      <RunTimeInformation>
                        <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="0" Batches="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" ActualExecutionMode="Row" ActualElapsedms="0" ActualCPUms="0" />
                      </RunTimeInformation>
                      <StreamAggregate>
                        <DefinedValues />
                        <GroupBy>
                          <ColumnReference Database="[adventureworks]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[T]" Alias="[T]" Column="ID" />
                        </GroupBy>
                        <RelOp AvgRowSize="11" EstimateCPU="4.18E-06" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="1" LogicalOp="Inner Join" NodeId="4" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Nested Loops" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.00985804">
                          <OutputList>
                            <ColumnReference Database="[adventureworks]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[T]" Alias="[T]" Column="ID" />
                          </OutputList>
                          <RunTimeInformation>
                            <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="0" Batches="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" ActualExecutionMode="Row" ActualElapsedms="0" ActualCPUms="0" />
                          </RunTimeInformation>
                          <NestedLoops Optimized="false">
                            <OuterReferences>
                              <ColumnReference Database="[adventureworks]" Schema="[sys]" Table="[xml_sxi_table_1463676262_256000]" Alias="[SomeText:1]" Column="pk1" />
                            </OuterReferences>
                            <RelOp AvgRowSize="16" EstimateCPU="4.18E-06" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="1" LogicalOp="Inner Join" NodeId="5" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Nested Loops" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.00657038">
                              <OutputList>
                                <ColumnReference Database="[adventureworks]" Schema="[sys]" Table="[xml_sxi_table_1463676262_256000]" Alias="[SomeText:1]" Column="pk1" />
                              </OutputList>
                              <RunTimeInformation>
                                <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="0" Batches="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" ActualExecutionMode="Row" ActualElapsedms="0" ActualCPUms="0" />
                              </RunTimeInformation>
                              <NestedLoops Optimized="false">
                                <OuterReferences>
                                  <ColumnReference Database="[adventureworks]" Schema="[sys]" Table="[xml_sxi_table_1463676262_256000]" Alias="[SomeText:1]" Column="pk1" />
                                  <ColumnReference Database="[adventureworks]" Schema="[sys]" Table="[xml_sxi_table_1463676262_256000]" Alias="[SomeText:1]" Column="row_id" />
                                </OuterReferences>
                                <RelOp AvgRowSize="15" EstimateCPU="0.0001581" EstimateIO="0.003125" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="1" EstimatedRowsRead="1" LogicalOp="Index Seek" NodeId="6" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Index Seek" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.0032831" TableCardinality="150002">
                                  <OutputList>
                                    <ColumnReference Database="[adventureworks]" Schema="[sys]" Table="[xml_sxi_table_1463676262_256000]" Alias="[SomeText:1]" Column="pk1" />
                                    <ColumnReference Database="[adventureworks]" Schema="[sys]" Table="[xml_sxi_table_1463676262_256000]" Alias="[SomeText:1]" Column="row_id" />
                                  </OutputList>
                                  <RunTimeInformation>
                                    <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="0" Batches="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" ActualExecutionMode="Row" ActualElapsedms="0" ActualCPUms="0" ActualScans="1" ActualLogicalReads="3" ActualPhysicalReads="0" ActualReadAheads="0" ActualLobLogicalReads="0" ActualLobPhysicalReads="0" ActualLobReadAheads="0" />
                                  </RunTimeInformation>
                                  <IndexScan Ordered="true" ScanDirection="FORWARD" ForcedIndex="false" ForceSeek="false" ForceScan="false" NoExpandHint="false" Storage="RowStore">
                                    <DefinedValues>
                                      <DefinedValue>
                                        <ColumnReference Database="[adventureworks]" Schema="[sys]" Table="[xml_sxi_table_1463676262_256000]" Alias="[SomeText:1]" Column="pk1" />
                                      </DefinedValue>
                                      <DefinedValue>
                                        <ColumnReference Database="[adventureworks]" Schema="[sys]" Table="[xml_sxi_table_1463676262_256000]" Alias="[SomeText:1]" Column="row_id" />
                                      </DefinedValue>
                                    </DefinedValues>
                                    <Object Database="[adventureworks]" Schema="[sys]" Table="[xml_sxi_table_1463676262_256000]" Index="[SIX_T_pathXQUERY]" Filtered="true" Alias="[SomeText:1]" IndexKind="SecondarySelectiveXML" Storage="RowStore" />
                                    <SeekPredicates>
                                      <SeekPredicateNew>
                                        <SeekKeys>
                                          <Prefix ScanType="EQ">
                                            <RangeColumns>
                                              <ColumnReference Database="[adventureworks]" Schema="[sys]" Table="[xml_sxi_table_1463676262_256000]" Alias="[SomeText:1]" Column="pathXQUERY_1_value" />
                                            </RangeColumns>
                                            <RangeExpressions>
                                              <ScalarOperator ScalarString="N''bbb''">
                                                <Const ConstValue="N''bbb''" />
                                              </ScalarOperator>
                                            </RangeExpressions>
                                          </Prefix>
                                        </SeekKeys>
                                      </SeekPredicateNew>
                                    </SeekPredicates>
                                  </IndexScan>
                                </RelOp>
                                <RelOp AvgRowSize="461" EstimateCPU="0.0001581" EstimateIO="0.003125" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="1" LogicalOp="Clustered Index Seek" NodeId="8" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Clustered Index Seek" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.0032831" TableCardinality="150002">
                                  <OutputList />
                                  <RunTimeInformation>
                                    <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="0" Batches="0" ActualEndOfScans="0" ActualExecutions="0" ActualExecutionMode="Row" ActualElapsedms="0" ActualCPUms="0" ActualScans="0" ActualLogicalReads="0" ActualPhysicalReads="0" ActualReadAheads="0" ActualLobLogicalReads="0" ActualLobPhysicalReads="0" ActualLobReadAheads="0" />
                                  </RunTimeInformation>
                                  <IndexScan Lookup="true" Ordered="true" ScanDirection="FORWARD" ForcedIndex="false" ForceSeek="false" ForceScan="false" NoExpandHint="false" Storage="RowStore">
                                    <DefinedValues />
                                    <Object Database="[adventureworks]" Schema="[sys]" Table="[xml_sxi_table_1463676262_256000]" Index="[SIX_T]" Alias="[SomeText:1]" TableReferenceId="-1" IndexKind="SelectiveXML" Storage="RowStore" />
                                    <SeekPredicates>
                                      <SeekPredicateNew>
                                        <SeekKeys>
                                          <Prefix ScanType="EQ">
                                            <RangeColumns>
                                              <ColumnReference Database="[adventureworks]" Schema="[sys]" Table="[xml_sxi_table_1463676262_256000]" Alias="[SomeText:1]" Column="pk1" />
                                              <ColumnReference Database="[adventureworks]" Schema="[sys]" Table="[xml_sxi_table_1463676262_256000]" Alias="[SomeText:1]" Column="row_id" />
                                            </RangeColumns>
                                            <RangeExpressions>
                                              <ScalarOperator ScalarString="[adventureworks].[sys].[xml_sxi_table_1463676262_256000].[pk1] as [SomeText:1].[pk1]">
                                                <Identifier>
                                                  <ColumnReference Database="[adventureworks]" Schema="[sys]" Table="[xml_sxi_table_1463676262_256000]" Alias="[SomeText:1]" Column="pk1" />
                                                </Identifier>
                                              </ScalarOperator>
                                              <ScalarOperator ScalarString="[adventureworks].[sys].[xml_sxi_table_1463676262_256000].[row_id] as [SomeText:1].[row_id]">
                                                <Identifier>
                                                  <ColumnReference Database="[adventureworks]" Schema="[sys]" Table="[xml_sxi_table_1463676262_256000]" Alias="[SomeText:1]" Column="row_id" />
                                                </Identifier>
                                              </ScalarOperator>
                                            </RangeExpressions>
                                          </Prefix>
                                        </SeekKeys>
                                      </SeekPredicateNew>
                                    </SeekPredicates>
                                    <Predicate>
                                      <ScalarOperator ScalarString="[adventureworks].[sys].[xml_sxi_table_1463676262_256000].[path_1_id] as [SomeText:1].[path_1_id] IS NOT NULL">
                                        <Logical Operation="IS NOT NULL">
                                          <ScalarOperator>
                                            <Identifier>
                                              <ColumnReference Database="[adventureworks]" Schema="[sys]" Table="[xml_sxi_table_1463676262_256000]" Alias="[SomeText:1]" Column="path_1_id" />
                                            </Identifier>
                                          </ScalarOperator>
                                        </Logical>
                                      </ScalarOperator>
                                    </Predicate>
                                  </IndexScan>
                                </RelOp>
                              </NestedLoops>
                            </RelOp>
                            <RelOp AvgRowSize="11" EstimateCPU="0.0001581" EstimateIO="0.003125" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="1" EstimatedRowsRead="1" LogicalOp="Clustered Index Seek" NodeId="9" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Clustered Index Seek" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.0032831" TableCardinality="200002">
                              <OutputList>
                                <ColumnReference Database="[adventureworks]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[T]" Alias="[T]" Column="ID" />
                              </OutputList>
                              <RunTimeInformation>
                                <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="0" Batches="0" ActualEndOfScans="0" ActualExecutions="0" ActualExecutionMode="Row" ActualElapsedms="0" ActualCPUms="0" ActualScans="0" ActualLogicalReads="0" ActualPhysicalReads="0" ActualReadAheads="0" ActualLobLogicalReads="0" ActualLobPhysicalReads="0" ActualLobReadAheads="0" />
                              </RunTimeInformation>
                              <IndexScan Ordered="true" ScanDirection="FORWARD" ForcedIndex="false" ForceSeek="false" ForceScan="false" NoExpandHint="false" Storage="RowStore">
                                <DefinedValues>
                                  <DefinedValue>
                                    <ColumnReference Database="[adventureworks]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[T]" Alias="[T]" Column="ID" />
                                  </DefinedValue>
                                </DefinedValues>
                                <Object Database="[adventureworks]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[T]" Index="[PK__T__3214EC27EF7043C5]" Alias="[T]" IndexKind="Clustered" Storage="RowStore" />
                                <SeekPredicates>
                                  <SeekPredicateNew>
                                    <SeekKeys>
                                      <Prefix ScanType="EQ">
                                        <RangeColumns>
                                          <ColumnReference Database="[adventureworks]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[T]" Alias="[T]" Column="ID" />
                                        </RangeColumns>
                                        <RangeExpressions>
                                          <ScalarOperator ScalarString="[adventureworks].[sys].[xml_sxi_table_1463676262_256000].[pk1] as [SomeText:1].[pk1]">
                                            <Identifier>
                                              <ColumnReference Database="[adventureworks]" Schema="[sys]" Table="[xml_sxi_table_1463676262_256000]" Alias="[SomeText:1]" Column="pk1" />
                                            </Identifier>
                                          </ScalarOperator>
                                        </RangeExpressions>
                                      </Prefix>
                                    </SeekKeys>
                                  </SeekPredicateNew>
                                </SeekPredicates>
                              </IndexScan>
                            </RelOp>
                          </NestedLoops>
                        </RelOp>
                      </StreamAggregate>
                    </RelOp>
                  </StreamAggregate>
                </RelOp>
              </ComputeScalar>
            </RelOp>
          </QueryPlan>
        </StmtSimple>
      </Statements>
    </Batch>
  </BatchSequence>
</ShowPlanXML>');
```

Comment: How do i use USE PLAN hint? You have example code for this query?

Comment: @SomeDude123 I added the explanation to the answer, let me know if you are stuck somewhere :)

Comment: Instead of USE PLAN you could use a variable and optimize for an unlikely value to get the seek plan. [db<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7cbe06edd8343002c6b476ebf589ef3a). @SomeDude123

Answer (score 6):

> The question is, how can i make counting by xml as fast as counting by
>   column?

Depending on how flexible you need to be with your xPath expression you could use [property promotion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/promote-frequently-used-xml-values-with-computed-columns?view=sql-server-ver15).

```
create function dbo.GetSomeText(@X xml) returns varchar(8) with schemabinding as
begin
  return @X.value('(/SomeText/text())[1]', 'varchar(8)');
end;

go

alter table dbo.T add SomeTextColumn as dbo.GetSomeText(XMLDoc);

go

create index T_IX_SomeText on dbo.T(SomeTextColumn);

go

select count(T.ID)
from dbo.T as T
where T.SomeTextColumn = 'MoreText';
```

[image]